# Snapshot Tables with Foreign Keys vs. Snapshot Tables with Real Values

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, data-modeling

On one of our client's database there are a few snapshot tables that summarize useful information from many other tables (e.g. what was the state of each customer in each period, etc).

The snapshot tables however, contain mostly foreign keys to their original tables. Therefore in order to obtain useful information about the snapshot, we have to join them multiple times to their corresponding tables. And these joins often take very long. Adding indexes to all `FL` columns in databases (or at least on columns in `WHERE` clauses in our queries) on the other hand, slows down the database significantly.

So my question is, wouldn't it be better to have snapshot tables with real values instead of foreign keys? And if the answer is negative, wouldn't it beat the purpose of snapshot tables if the original tables are updated (e.g. if an was called 'Candle' and now 'Lamp' of course are snapshot remains consistent but is it really snapshot in this case?)

Comment: Ask your self: What happens if some entries are deleted? The snapshot containing the FK's will be of no use any longer

Comment: @lokusking exactly. Wouldn't it make sense to have real values then?

Comment: This is the only thing that makes sense imo.

Comment: You don't need joins to resolve foreign keys. You need joins to resolve *surrogate* keys--integers (usually) that take the place of "real values".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lean towards storing the actual data rather than FK values for the reason you mentioned. That said, a better solution might be to relocate this historical data along with relevant attributes (IE Dimensions) and restructure it for analysis. [Data warehousing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) is certainly a solution for this, although these can be very large-scale projects so you'd need to understand the value and scope it appropriately. However, even a light-weight star schema that targets the specific events they're trying to capture could be a better solution than a large historical table with relationships to transaction-based tables (especially if the query logic against the related tables is complex).